# Forcing Tor to use a given IP address for outbound connections

Tags: linux, tor

I have a network card with 3 IPs on OpenVZ virtual node (device `venet0`). Let's call them A,B,C. By default, Tor opens outbound connections from address A. I want it to use only B.

In `torrc` file the only line that deals with IP addresses is `DirListenAddress B`, but it's not sufficient. Because even if Tor listens on that IP address all outgoing connections will be bound to A.

Is it possible to tell Tor only to use address B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking around I found:

```
OutboundBindAddress B
```

[Explanation](http://en.linuxreviews.org/HOWTO_setup_a_Tor-server)

Note OutboundBindAddress. This is the IP Tor-users will be exiting your server from. This setting should also be set to your servers IP if it has a real IP (not behind a NAT firewall with something like 192.168.1.2), even if it only has one, because then anyone exiting from your server to your server will then be coming from that IP and not from 127.0.0.1 (which they would if OutboundBindAddress is not set).